# Cordova 3.4, Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I was building my project perfectly but after updating iOS to 7.1, I was then forced to update Xcode 5.1 and now I'm getting error and warning messages:

**4S 7.04** – builds – no error or warning messages

**5S 7.1** – doesn’t build – mixture of error and warning messages:
26 x *Value conversion issue
Implicit conversion loses integer precision:*

12 x Linker build errors

Then I do the steps outlined in this blog post to remove linker errors – delete all conditional architecture and make sure arm64 is in the all the projects and targets: http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/

**4S 7.04** – builds – warning messages:
12 x *Format String Issue
Values of type ‘NSInteger’ should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to ‘long’ instead*

**5S 7.1** – doesn’t build – warning messages:
26 x *Value conversion issue
Implicit conversion loses integer precision:*

12 x *Format String Issue
Values of type ‘NSInteger’ should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to ‘long’ instead*

I think the warning messages are now affecting the badges as they are not reseting correctly

Are the warning messages relevant? And would they likely be affecting resetting the badges?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have gone back and forth with this for a while and I've got a few possible solutions for you.

1. Make sure in Xcode you are selecting both your project and the target within that project also and make sure your settings are setup like the forum post you mentioned.
2. Make sure you also change the settings on the CordovaLib project as well. Both the project and the target need to be changed, but it's slightly different. you also need to add i386 as a supported platform in the cordova project, but is not needed in yours.
3. Other things to check are.... Make sure you are using the right kind of provisioning profile... ie. Distribution for production phone builds and Development for team builds and testing on your device.
4. Check and make sure you are not missing a library you needed to import. You can usually tell if you are missing a library by the mach-o linker errors though. 
   Example: I removed a plugin from my phonegap project via command line. Well then I added it back and my project would not build using the 'phonegap build ios' command. I had to open the XCode version of my project within xcode then re-import the AudioToolbox library under the Linked files and then I was able to build again via command line.

Good luck, comment here if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestions. Unfortunately I've gone thorough the list and checked them all off - back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 0):

Please check my attached images might be it will helpful for you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]